# Something faster than MS Access 2007, Fast Portable Database Recommendations?

Tags: .net, database, performance, ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2007 for insert and read data in my application but it's really slow.

I've got a long running application and if I run it from the memory it takes about **5** minutes, with MS Access 2007 it takes about **13** minutes!

I'm looking for a faster yet portable database option, I'm using .NET . I'm not looking for advanced relational database stuff, as soon as it works like a decent database, it's enough for me.

**EDIT :**

I'm mostly doing concurrent inserts from multiple threads.

**RESULTS**

I've tried SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 SP1 and it's almost same with running from memory so %400 times faster than access + instead of a 72MB of dependency I've got 1.5MB dependency which is great.

*P.S. Database is normalised, clean, compacted and I'm using stored_procedures and native client. So I've tried so many things to make it faster already.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Express 2008. It's free, and it's SQL Server.

Comment: Is it portable like MS Access, copy-paste and connect? without a windows service?

Comment: First of all, I suggest you actually try the installer, to see if you can run it with defaults - no UI. Second, if necessary, consider SQL Server Compact Edition, which is more like Access, working with individual files.

Comment: Actually my app already can switch to SQL Server 2000 and works fine. So I'm downloading compact edition and see if it works better.

Comment: Well actually tried and it's almost the same speed with working on the memory, awesome!

Comment: it does not have a self contained driver... requires install of the driver

Comment: @jle: Slough didn't seem to mind. See his comment on 4/6/2009. 400% improvement is not too bad.

Answer (score 8):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Comment: performance-wise is it better? I've seen couple of comments in the forums claims it's better, but couldn't find any benchmark or something like that.

Comment: It is faster. Not to put down Access, but almost any database you can use in your situation is faster; Access's strength is in it's end user tools for creating forms and reports.

Comment: very fast, driver is self contained, no install required... and also very scalable

Answer (score 3):

From the sqlite wiki:

SQLite is the speed demon of choice for systems that don't make heavy use of concurrent connections and complicated database features. If you need a lot of concurrent connections, SQLite probably isn't the best choice. But if you need a lot of speed and a simple setup for a single connection, SQLite is the best thing I've seen.

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=PerformanceConsiderations

You might also want to take a look at mysql, pgsql or mssql (CE or Express (Both Free)),
depending on your needs.

---

**Edit**: Based on your comments, you will probably need something that runs on a server like mysql, pgsql or mssql (express)

---

**Edit2**: If you are mostly doing inserts, make sure you don't have unused indexes in your table, since indexes can make insert/updates a bit slower.

Comment: It's not concurrent connections but more like concurrent inserts coming from so 10-50 threads. BTW thanks for the link.

Comment: I've just read the page, I think sqlite will suffer from write locks in my case, according to that page sqlite is not good about that.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't think you're going to get much faster results.  Your program is probably I/O bound, which means that the speed of the disk is slowing you down.

You can try SQL Compact Edition (CE), but I suspect you will see as slow or slower results from any other tool.

Comment: SQL Compact Edition support stored procedures yet? If so, adjusting for lack of stored procedures can be factored into migration plans.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Firebird : www.firebirdsql.org

It's free and very easy to use. There is some good .net drivers.

If you sell your application : MySQL is not free.